# kotlin how to parse text into a list of data class

Tags: kotlin

I have a kotlin data class described as:

```
data class Credentials(val p: String, val id: String, val key: String, val pass: String, val out: String)
```

I am trying to read from 2 text files located in a directory, and put them into this data class.

**How the data looks:**

**config file**

```
[user1]
out = specialk
id = mike

[user2]
out = specialk
id = mike

[user3]
out = specialk
id = mike
```

**credentials file**

```
[user1]
key = qwer1
pass = 3452

[user2]
key = qwer3
pass = 345232

[user3]
key = qwer5
pass = 3452gfd
```

Setting it up:

```
val homepath = System.getProperty("user.home")
val config = "$homepath/foobar"
val cred= "$homepath/credbar"

val configStream: InputStream = File(config).inputStream()
val credStream: InputStream = File(cred).inputStream()
```

This next part is something I am unsure of. What I think is that I should be reading each `stream` and putting it into a list of `data class` grouped by the user. However, I'm not sure how that should be accomplished.

```
configStream.bufferedReader().forEachLine {
    // put to data class here. 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't write single comment cause i am new at Stackowerflow. Sorry about that. If this file holds your app backup you can take backup as JSON file. This is much easier than this.

Firstly you need to add Gson dependency in your project

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
```

Secondly you need to two parser object that is for make parse to data class to JSON and JSON to data class.

You need to declare your export and import type as below

```
val exportType = object : TypeToken<List<Credentials>>() {}.type
```

And after that for convert your data to JSON String you can use this

```
private fun List<Credentials>.toJson() = Gson().toJson(this, exportType)
```

this code returns String.

and if you want to convert JSON to String you can use this code

```
private fun fromJson(str: String): List<Credentials> {
    return try {
        Gson().fromJson(str, exportType)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e("From Json Exception", "$e")
        emptyList()
    }
}
```

this code returns list of your data class.

I hope this can help you. I did not ask is this you want to do because my Stacowerflow account is new.

Comment: Your code assumes that OP's 2 files are in JSON format, but they are not, and I don't see any reason OP will do it

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko  I know they are not JSON file. I thought he was made this format and if he change the format to JSON it is easier than this.

Comment: Hmm, unfortunately the format that I will be receiving, is similar to INI format instead of a json format. but thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

Basically I would try to convert your streams into two strings

```
val configInputFileString = convertStreamToString(configStream)
val credentialsInputFileString = convertStreamToString(credStream)
```

You can easily convert a stream by using this function:

```kotiln
fun convertStreamToString(stream: InputStream?): String? {
        val reader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(stream))
        val sb = StringBuilder()
        var line: String? = null
        while (reader.readLine().also { line = it } != null) {
            sb.append(line).append("\n")
        }
        reader.close()
        return sb.toString()
    }
```

Once you have the two streams, I would define to different data classes to get the elements of the streams:

- `data class UserConfig(val placeholder: String, val out: String, val id: String)`
- `data class UserCredentials(val placeholder: String, val key: String, val pass: String)`

for each stream you need to get each row, splitting by new line character `\n` and clearing unuseful parts:

```kotlin
private fun getUserConfigs(elements: List<String>): ArrayList<UserConfig> {
        val configs = arrayListOf<UserConfig>()
        for (element in elements) {
            val splittedConfig = element
                    .replace("out = ", "")
                    .replace("id = ", "")
                    .split("\n")
            val config = UserConfig(splittedConfig[0], splittedConfig[1], splittedConfig[2])
            configs.add(config)
        }
        return configs
    }

    private fun getUserCredentials(elements: List<String>): ArrayList<UserCredentials> {
        val credentials = arrayListOf<UserCredentials>()
        for (element in elements) {
            val splittedCredentials = element
                    .replace("key = ", "")
                    .replace("pass = ", "")
                    .split("\n")
            val config = UserCredentials(splittedCredentials[0], splittedCredentials[1], splittedCredentials[2])
            credentials.add(config)
        }
        return credentials
    }
```

Now you can map `userConfig` and `credentialConfigs` in a `usersMap`

```kotlin
 val userConfigs = getUserConfigs(configInputFileString!!.split("\n\n"))
        val credentialConfigs = getUserCredentials(credentialsInputFileString!!.split("\n\n"))

        val usersMap = userConfigs.map { userConfig ->
            userConfig to credentialConfigs.find { it.placeholder == userConfig.placeholder }
        }
```

Finally you can transform the `usersMap` to match your `data class` by doing:

```
val credentials = usersMap.map { Credentials(it.first.placeholder, it.first.id, it.second!!.key, it.second!!.pass, it.first.out) }
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as your files seem to be of Windows INI format you can use third-party library [Ini4J](http://ini4j.sourceforge.net/) to parse them.

Parse both files and merge two `Ini`s into list of Credentials

```
val configs = Ini(File(config))
val credentials = Ini(File(cred))

val result: List<Credentials> = configs.keySet().map { user ->
    Credentials(p = user, // or whatever 'p' is
            id = configs.get(user, "id")!!, 
            key = credentials.get(user, "key")!!, 
            pass = credentials.get(user, "pass")!!, 
            out = configs.get(user, "out")!!)
}
```